# retrieving values from the array of values from the server

Tags: android, exception, arrays

I have a piece of code and am trying to trace it. The code is:

```
if(response != null) 
        { 

            String line="";

            String strLine[]=new String[7];

            docids.clear();
            names.clear();
            specl.clear();
            qual.clear();
            exp.clear();
            loc.clear();
            cid.clear();


            passmsg="";

            //ArrayList<String> arrloc = new ArrayList<String>();

            InputStream inputstream = response.getEntity().getContent(); 

            //line[] = convertStreamToString(inputstream); 

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
            try 
                {

                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 

                    {

                    Toast.makeText(this,"Line:"+line , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    strLine= line.split(",");
                    String errmsg,errno;


                    Integer a=Integer.parseInt(strLine[0]);


                    if(a==0)
                    {


                     Toast.makeText(this,"NO SESSION!!!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                     startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                    }

                    else if(a==1)
                    {

                        errno=strLine[1];
                        if(errno.equals("61")||errno.equals("49"))
                            {
                            errmsg=strLine[2];
                             Toast.makeText(this,errmsg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        else if(errno.equals("194"))
                        {
                        errmsg=strLine[2];
                         Toast.makeText(this,errmsg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         e1.setText("");
                         e1.requestFocus();
                        }

                        else if(errno.equals("195"))
                        {
                        errmsg=strLine[2];
                         Toast.makeText(this,errmsg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         e2.setText("");
                         e2.requestFocus();
                        }

                        else if(errno.equals("62")) 
                            {
                            //whc=strLine[3];

                                whc=which.toString();

                            if(whc.equals("1"))
                            {
                                passmsg="Doctor List,Specialties";
                            }

                            else if(whc.equals("2"))
                            {
                                passmsg="Doctor List,City Locations";
                            }
                            docids.add(strLine[3]);



                            names.add("Dr."+strLine[4]);

                            String sp=replace(strLine[5]);
                            specl.add("Specialities:"+sp);

                            String q=replace(strLine[6]);
                            qual.add("Qual:"+q);

                            exp.add("Exp:"+strLine[7]+"yrs");

                            if(whc.equals("1"))
                            {
                                loc.add(replace(strLine[8]));
                            }

                            else if(whc.equals("2"))
                            {

                                cid.add(strLine[9]);
                                loc.add(strLine[8]+","+strLine[10]);
                            }
```

Code executes perfectly but my doubt is when array is declared as of 7 values **String strLine[]=new String[7];** we can only store values from 0 to 6th location. How is it possible to store and retrieve values of 7th location onwards?

```
cid.add(strLine[9]);
loc.add(strLine[8]+","+strLine[10]);
```

Why am I not getting ArrayOutOfBoundException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strLine= line.split(",");
```

Because of above line a new array of string was created.
So the size of this array is same as the element returned from split function.

```
strLine= new String[7];
```

Above line is meaning-less as the reference is broken when you assigned a new array to strLine.

You can just write 
    strLine=null;

And letter on:

```
strLine= line.split(",");
```

Will initialize your string array.

Answer (score 0):

string array's can only be initialized once and only once.

your solution would be:

```
String a[]; 
a = new String[no_of_strings_received];
```

instantiate the array depending upon the number of responses received dynamically!

Comment: same way the string is declared. But my doubt is when is string array is declared as of 7 values how its possible to store more than 7 values??